# Cannot load asset inside a framework

Tags: xcode, assets

I'm trying to load an asset stored inside an asset directory I've created like this:

```
if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "packages") {
    print("loaded")
} else {
    print("not loaded")
}
```

This works fine if I'm inside an application project, but it does NOT work if I'm inside a framework project. What can I do?

I've found this [thread](http://www.openradar.me/22254994) that mention it's not possible to do so. Is it the reason why I'm having troubles? If yes, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to use the Asset directory inside a framework, it seems impossible.
However I managed to handle my JSON file using a Bundle. Here is what I did.

1. Create a new group that will contain your resources
2. Drag and drop your files into this group

Now you have to use a Bundle to load your files :

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: <your.bundle.name>)
```

You can find your bundle name by clicking on your Framework target, then select the bundle you need. In the General tab take what's in the Bundle Identifier field.

[image]

This will allow you to access any file of your bundle.

For every file, load your file path :

```
let path = bundle.path(forResource: <filenameWitoutExtension>, ofType: <yourFileType>)
```

Finally, you can load your file :

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
```

I don't know if this is a good practice or not, but at least I can access to the resources of my framework. Hope it will help.